# Is it possible for the intersection of nonempty subset to be empty?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

**The question is:**

Give an example of nonempty closed sets $$C_1  \supset C_2  \supset \ ... $$ such that the intersection $$\bigcap U_i$$ is empty.

I think that this is **not** possible. If the set $A$ is a subset of the set $B$ then all elements in $A$ are contained in $B$. In the above case, unless $U_n$ is empty, the intersection $U_i$ will be nonempty. Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the closed intervals $[n,\infty)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For compact closed sets it is [famously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) not possible.

For closed sets, it can be empty: consider $C_n=[n,\infty)$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Much better counterexample than what I was about to offer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the difference between the compact and non-compact cases is that to get an empty intersection, the sets have to "run off to infinity". And that's the simplest way to do it I could think of. Compactness prevents the running away to infinity.

Comment: I think it's important to think about *why* this works. A decreasing sequence of sets is analogous to a decreasing sequence of numbers. The intersection of all of them is a lower-bound for the sequence-- it is a set which is contained in all of them. So what's a decreasing sequence of sets with no lower bound? That reminds me of a decreasing sequence of numbers with no lower bound.

Comment: Note too that the parent space is critical. The sets $(0,1/n]$ are closed in $\mathbb R \setminus\{0\}$ but have empty intersection.

Comment: I was thinking of closed intervals in $\Bbb Q$ converging on an irrational number.